# Creating new worksheet and renaming from a list but also to insert a value from the list to the new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping for help with something I am working on. 
1. I would like to create a vba code that creates new worksheets against a "template worksheet" and rename them based on a separate "List worksheet" that contains a list of serial numbers. I have managed to find a vba code that does this. 
2. I will like to automatically copy each serial number from the same "List worksheet" to the Column D5 of each newly created worksheet.
For example, the first created worksheet is renamed as "12345" and the worksheet should have 12345 copied in column "D5".

This is the vba that does the first action. But I really need a kind soul to help advice the 2nd action.

```
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("List")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=sh
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the value in cell D5 of the new worksheet:

```
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("List")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=sh
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much YowE3K. I was about to pull out most of my hair.

Comment: Hi All, hoping to have some help again please. Two questions I have is how can I.................(1) Add a predefine text for each newly created template (for example I need the word "Serial Number" in front of 12345 copied from the list. (2) Using the list, I would like to generate new files from 2 separately named templates (example worksheet "Template" and "Template2".

Comment: It works perfectly and thank you again. Can you help with my earlier message please?

Comment: @Ben If you have a new problem that you can't solve, create a new question.  Then I, or someone else, will be able to help.  (But, before you post the new question and get severely downvoted for not having done any research re your first item, check out how to use the `&` string concatenation operator.  You are already using it in a couple of places in your current code - you should be able to work out how to use it to put a word in front of another value.)